# Is it possible to search multiple containers in an a single line of code?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a scraper that scrapes a page for products. Every container is set up the same way, but they are grouped into several different s. I can write code and loops for each class of containers, but I was thinking it would be clearer to write on line for all of them. Is this possible?

The HTML code for each of the four classes is identical with the exception of the class name and the text that I'm scraping. It looks like this:

```
<tr class="product">

        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="LINK">COMPANY NAME
        </td>
        <td data-order="PRODUCT NUMBER">
                            <div class="productnum">PRODUCT NUMBER</div>
                                        <img src="BRAND LOGO">
        </td>
        <td>

                CATEGORIES TEXT
        </td>
```

The next class will then be:

```
<tr class="productGold">

        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="LINK">COMPANY NAME
        </td>
        <td data-order="PRODUCT NUMBER">
                            <div class="productnum">PRODUCT NUMBER</div>
                                        <img src="BRAND LOGO">
        </td>
        <td>

                CATEGORIES TEXT
        </td>
```

...and so on.

Currently, I use the following line of code to get all the products in a particular class:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("tr",{"class":"productGold"})
```

Then I write the loop and export it to csv. Then I repeat for each of the four classes:

```
{"class":"productGold"}), {"class":"productSilver"}), " 
{"class":"productBronze"}), and {"class":"product"})
```

Can I write a single line of code that will find all the products in all the classes and then iterate through the page once as opposed to:

```py
containers = page_soup.findAll("tr",{"class":"productGold"})

product_names = []
product_numbers = []
categories = []

with open('My-File.csv','w') as f:
    csv_out = csv.writer(f)
    for container in containers:
            product_name = container.a.text
            product_number = container.div.text
            category = container.select_one('td:nth-of-type(4)').text.strip() 

            product_names.append(product_name)
            proudct_numbers.append(product_number)
            categories.append(category)

            csv_out.writerow([product_name, product_number, category])
```

Then:

```py
containers = page_soup.findAll("tr",{"class":"productSilver"})

product_names = []
product_numbers = []
categories = []

with open('My-File_1.csv','w') as f:
    csv_out = csv.writer(f)
    for container in containers:
            product_name = container.a.text
            product_number = container.div.text
            category = container.select_one('td:nth-of-type(4)').text.strip() 

            product_names.append(product_name)
            proudct_numbers.append(product_number)
            categories.append(category)

            csv_out.writerow([product_name, product_number, category])
```

Then the same for `{"class":"productBronze"}) and {"class":"product"})`?

I think I can do it in this line:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("tr",{"class":"productGold"})
```

but I'm not making it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try ```containers = page_soup('tr', 'product')```?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of ```My-File_1.csv``` file contents?

Comment: You'll need to provide a couple of examples of the code for each of your 4 product classes so people can try ideas out.

Comment: @JackFleeting, Thanks. Do you mean the HTML code or my Python code? I gave two examples of my Python code above? They are identical (because the HTML is identical) w/ the exception of the ```{"class":"productXXXX"}```. I can go ahead & write the script so that I have four loops w/ different ```containers = page_soup.findAll("tr",{"class":"productSilver"})``` above each (and have each write a separate .csv file, but because the loops are exactly the same save the each writing to its own .csv file, it felt like I should just be able to edit the ```containers =``` line to scrape ALL products.

Comment: @accdias, The .csv files are identical in form. One column with the product name, one column with the product number and one column with the categories. It would actually be better to have all products in one .csv since they are identical save the class they were assigned. Right now, I'm merging the four .csv files in Excel.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear; I meant the html code containing these 4 classes (or the whole URL, if available).

Comment: @accdias I tried ```containers = page_soup('tr', 'product')``` and I then just got one result.

Comment: I meant to ask for the html code instead. But you already have an answer using regular expressions. That's the way to go.

Comment: @JackFleeting I added examples of the HTML code in the original question.

Comment: Is my answer not helping you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular expression it will find all classes related to product.

```
import re
containers = page_soup.findAll("tr",class_=re.compile('product'))
```

Or You can use `lamda` function

```
containers = page_soup.findAll(lambda tag:tag.name == "tr" and [tag.attrs=='class'.startswith('product')])
```

Comment: It looks like the first option is only returning the "productGold" class, but the ```lamda``` option looks promising!

Comment: Great.If it really helps you can you accept my answer and up vote for future followers.Thanks.

Comment: The ```lamda``` option helped. I'm finding what may be a problem deep in the HTML code now that is not allowing my code to work. I'm going to approve this answer, however, because I think it answers the question I originally asked. Thank you!

Comment: @PythonFisher : Strange the html you have posted its returns me correct result using both options.

Comment: Yes. But when I get deeper into the almost 1500 products in the HTML, I am seeing that they are not all consistent with the HTML I posted. I taking a deeper look now. Thanks again for your help! You got me on the right track for sure.